# Entity Framework (6) Performance Optimisation advice

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an ADO.Net Data Access layer in my application that uses basic ADO.Net coupled with CRUD stored procedures (one per operation e.g. Select_myTable, Insert_myTable). As you can imagine, in a large system (like ours), the number of DB objects required by the DA layer is pretty large.

I've been looking at the possibility of refactoring the layer classes into EF POCO classes. I've managed to do this, but when I try to performance test, it gets pretty horrific. Using the class below (create object, set Key to desired value, call dataselect), 100000 runs of data loading only takes about 47 seconds (there are only a handful of records in the DB). Whereas the Stored Proc method takes about 7 seconds.

I'm looking for advice on how to optimise this - as a point of note, I cannot change the exposed functionality of the layer - only how it implements the methods (i.e. I can't pass responsibility for context ownership to the BO layer)

Thanks

```
public class DAContext : DbContext
{
    public DAContext(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction trans)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
        this.Database.UseTransaction(trans);

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Stop Pluralising the Object names for table names.
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        //Set any property ending in "Key" as a key type.
        modelBuilder.Properties().Where(prop => prop.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("key")).Configure(config => config.IsKey());

    }

    public DbSet<MyTable> MyTable{ get; set; }
}

public class MyTable : DataAccessBase
{

    #region Properties

    public int MyTableKey { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    public MyTable()
    {
        //Set Default Values.
        Active = true;
        Name = string.Empty;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override void DataSelect(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        using (DAContext ctxt = new DAContext(connection, transaction))
        {

            var limitquery = from C in ctxt.MyTable
                             select C;


            //TODO: Sort the Query
            limitquery = FilterQuery(limitquery);

            var limit = limitquery.FirstOrDefault();

            if (limit != null)
            {
                this.Name = limit.Name;
                this.Description = limit.Description;
                this.Active = limit.Active;
                this.CreatedBy = limit.CreatedBy;
                this.CreatedDate = limit.CreatedDate;
                this.ModifiedBy = limit.ModifiedBy;
                this.ModifiedDate = limit.ModifiedDate;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("No MyTable with the specified Key ({0}) exists", this.MyTableKey));
            }
        }
    }

    private IQueryable<MyTable1> FilterQuery(IQueryable<MyTable1> limitQuery)
    {
        if (MyTableKey > 0) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.MyTableKey == MyTableKey);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.Name == Name);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description)) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.Description == Description);
        if (Active) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.Active == true);
        if (CreatedBy > 0) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.CreatedBy == CreatedBy);
        if (ModifiedBy > 0) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.ModifiedBy == ModifiedBy);
        if (CreatedDate > DateTime.MinValue) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.CreatedDate == CreatedDate);
        if (ModifiedDate > DateTime.MinValue) limitQuery = limitQuery.Where(C => C.ModifiedDate == ModifiedDate);

        return limitQuery;
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: Just as another comment, I added an additional query type to the comparison: ADO.Net (with datareader - building the query in memory and not using a Stored proc). The timings were: **POCO EF**: 47s; **Stored Proc**: 7s; **ADO.Net**: 5s

Comment: So have you reviewed any of the queries that EF is executing? You may be unwittingly causing it to use inefficient queries. Also, without posting your ADO.NET/Stored Proc code we can't tell if you are doing things differently in each of the scenarios. Here you are spinning up a new context 100,000 times. I typically see hand-rolled DALs reuse connections.

Answer (score 1):

Selects are slow with tracking on. You should definitely turn off tracking and measure again.

Take a look at my benchmarks

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2013/05/yet-another-orm-micro-benchmark-part-23_15.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding `.AsNoTracking()` to `var limitquery = from C in ctxt.CoverageLimit` and, whilst I did see a performance improvement down to 46s (POCO) vs 7s (Stored Proc), it wasn't really very significant. Unfortunately, unless I can make the timings near comparable there's no way I can get buy-in for this change

Comment: I have always used SqlConnection/SqlCommand/SqlDataReader exclusively for thier high performance and I prefer writing my own TSQL queries instead of using LINQ.  I am finding that I can simplify code without sacrificing performance by adding TableAttribute and ColumnAttribute to my classes and their properties, then constructing generic methods to read those classes directly from an SqlDataReader with signatures like List<T> ReadEntities<T>(SqlDataReader reader, T type, string tableAlias = null) or List<List<object>> ReadEntities(SqlDataReader reader, Type[] types, string[] tableAliases ).

Answer (score 0):

This might be just a hunch, but ... In your stored procedure, the filters are well defined and the SP is in a compiled state with decent execution plan. Your EF query gets constructed from scratch and recompiled on every use. So the task now becomes to devise a way to compile and preserve your EF queries, between uses. One way would be to rewrite your FilterQuery to not rely on fluent conditional method chain. Instead of appending, or not, a new condition every time your parameter set changes, convert it into one, where the filter is either applied when condition is met, or overridden by something like 1.Equals(1) when not. This way your query can be complied and made available for re-use. The backing SQL will look funky, but execution times should improve. Alternatively you could devise Aspect Oriented Programming approach, where compiled queries would be re-used based on parameter values. If I will have the time, I will post a sample on Code Project.

Comment: EF6 does not get recompiled on every use. That was the case prior to version 5.

Comment: Are you sure @DarrellNorton that in the scenario above the limitQuery variable would not be recompiled every time it is used?

Comment: @Derek: EF keeps it in its own internal cache, so unless you are closing down the AppDomain and starting over, it should be cached. Happy to be proven otherwise.

Comment: That is quite intriguing. The variable limitquery is defined within a loop. I recognize that its "signature" from one loop to another will be the same, so technically, it could be recognizable using a number of ways, thus "cacheable". That is wicked cool if EF does it :)